# Can you get a virus on a non jailbroken iphone

Tags: iphone, virus

Is it possible to get a virus from an emoji on a non jail broken iphone5? Also is cellular data the same as mobile data? Thanks

Comment: No and yes. Next time look up your questions before posting them

Comment: You asked two not-all-that-related questions in one. Just don't do that. Also try googling before you ask a question here. But welcome to Stack Overflow! Feel free to ask more questions in the future, really.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can not get a virus from an emoji as they are local to the iOS system and therefore not external. If you are referencing the iPhone bug from quite a while where the phone would restart after being sent a message then that was not a virus but instead a failure in the uni code support for certain joined characters in the notification center. This bug has been patched.

Yes, mobile and cellular data are the same. If you know someone who's phone says one of the two that is different than yours it is because iPhones use the most common language for this setting based the language is set for (aka. English, British English, Australian English, etc.).